# Equivalent dlog for debugging in javascript?

Tags: javascript, tizen, journal

I succeded to play an audio file however now I would like to make a tag appear in JavaScript. In fact, I want to see when the myplay is run. In C I know that there is “dlog” function but in Javascript I don’t know. Could you help me ? because I want to show my tag in the log view but this is a web app not native application.

```js
function setLimitExceeded(exceeded) {
    if (exceeded) {
        page.classList.add('limit-excedeed');
        vibration.start();                          // la montre vibre 
        myMedia.play();                             //joue le morceau 
       // Log.i("Acachan", "music play");           //EXEMPLE  TAG
       
    } else {
        page.classList.remove('limit-excedeed');
        vibration.stop();
        /*setTimeout(function()             //stop le morceau apres tant de minute 
                {
                  myMedia.stop();           //on arrete le morceau 
                }, 5000);                   //5s après*/
        
        myMedia.pause();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has several built-in logging utilities that could be used in a web app:

- [`console.log()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log)
- [`console.info()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/info)
- [`console.trace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/trace)
- [`console.debug()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/debug)
- [`console.warn()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/warn)
- [`console.error()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/error)
- (and others...)